# Catalina: How to add System Events to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Automation?

Tags: applescript, security, script, error, automation

## The problem

In a [script](https://brettterpstra.com/2011/03/07/watch-for-file-changes-and-refresh-your-browser-automatically/) I'm using AppleScript to reload the browser when a change happens. I start this in the builtin terminal of my IDE, WebStorm.
Since MacOS Catalina this yields the following error:

**English**

`execution error: System Events got an error: osascript is not allowed to send keystrokes. (1002)`

**German/Deutsch**

`execution error: „System Events“ hat einen Fehler erhalten: osascript ist nicht berechtigt, Tastatureingaben zu senden. (1002)`

## The solution

I added `/usr/bin/osascript` and WebStorm.app via 'Choose File' dialog to `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility` (German/Deutsch:   `Systemeinstellungen > Sicherheit > Datenschtuz > Bedienungshilfen`).
But since Catalina/Mojave it must also appear under the new section Automation. Only there is no 'Choose File' dialog and when running the script no [confirmation dialog](https://macosxautomation.com/automator/security.html) pops up so [(un)checkable entry](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchl07817563/) is created.

How can I allow System Events under `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Automation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`osascript -e 'tell application "System Events"' -e 'keystroke "echo hi"' -e end tell`
will add an entry System Events under ther terminal emulator where you run it from in the automation section.

- If you receive execution error 1002 again, uncheck and recheck System
  Events under Automation again.
- If you receive  execution error -1743: Remove the app from the Accessibility/Bedienungshilfen section and add it again

  - *execution error: Not authorized to send Apple Events to System Events. (error -1743)*
  - *execution error: Keine Berechtigung zum Senden von Apple-Events an System Events. (-1743)*
- If you receive execution error -1719: Add `/System/Library/CoreServices/System Events.app` to Accessibility/Bedienungshilfen via 'Choose File' dialog

  - execution error: System Events got an error: osascript is not allowed assistive access. (-1719)

Possibly lock and unlock between rechecking/readding or run multiple times or prefixed by `sleep 1 &&`. These new security settings unfortunately [still seem a bit messy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51847089) (*good links for further reading there!*):

> Hopefully this gets worked out before Mojave ships.

Nope :-(

By the way, `osascript -e 'tell application "System Events"' -e "keystroke key code 53" -e end tell` ran twice will add the entry for the program itself under the program.

[image: Screenshot from MacOS System Settings showing the relevant options]