# AppleScript click at times out

Tags: applescript, mouse

I am unable to use any AppleScript `click at` functionality:

```
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
    end tell

    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "Finder"
            click at {500, 500}
        end tell
    end tell
```

System Event keyboard keys, menus and windows are working fine but for `click at` I get the error:

> System Events got an error: AppleEvent timed out.

Makes no difference if I use `tell application process "Finder"` or not.

I have Script Editor and System Events added and enabled in **Privacy & Security** > **Accessibility**.

I see there is an Automation tab, but I see no way to add anything there.

I can't find current instructions for Ventura to set up System Event mouse input. Everything on the subject doesn't match my Settings such as:

- [Catalina: How to add System Events to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Automation?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/394980/catalina-how-to-add-system-events-to-system-preferences-security-privacy)
- [Applescript error "System Events got an error: Script Editor is not allowed assistive access."](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253248516)

I think it must be a setting because what I'm trying to accomplish is very much known to work.